# How to connect appsettings.json with IConfiguration on worker service c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I was creating a background service and I keep the database connection sentence on the appsettings.json file, which I need to access through program.cs. I am using .Net 6 version. How can I access it with IConfiguration.
Program.cs file :
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for this?
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
 IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
});

Comment: You dont have to use Ihost, use webapplication builder also work on worker service.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference your `IConfiguration` inside the `.ConfigureServices()` method. There is an overload that provides a `HostBuilderContext`:

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        IConfiguration config = hostContext.Configuration;
        // Do stuff with config
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();
```